# htaccess to write URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite URL for users using htaccess file so that users can easily remember and make sure address bar stay cool.I accomplished to rewrite -

## Rewrited URL

*www.mysite.com/index.php?profile=2345*

## Actual URL wanted

*www.mysite.com/profile/2345*

## .htaccess

```
RewriteRule    ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?profile=$1    [NC,L]
```

## Unable to

**1. Multiple **

*www.mysite.com/profile=2345&a=65&b=34&c=7&d=54*

**into**

*www.mysite.com/profile/2345/a/65/b/34/c/7/d/54*

**2. Is it possible to go further like?**

*profile.mysite.com/2345/a/65/b/34/c/7/d/54*

Comment: What is the URL you want to give users ? is it (1) www.mysite.com/profile=2345&a=65&b=34&c=7&d=54 or  (2) 
www.mysite.com/profile/2345/a/65/b/34/c/7/d/54 ??

Comment: I think it is the second one :)

Comment: @DusanBajic do u want to help him then? I'm kinda busy for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/a/([0-9]+)/b/([0-9]+)/c/([0-9]+)/d/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?profile=$1&a=$2&b=$3&c=$4&d=$5 [NC,L]
```

2.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^profile\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/a/([0-9]+)/b/([0-9]+)/c/([0-9]+)/d/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?profile=$1&a=$2&b=$3&c=$4&d=$5 [NC,L]
```

3.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?%1=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?%1=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?%1=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([abcd])/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?%1=$1&$2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?%1=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: if any of the (a,b,c,d) is not set it shows error.sometimes i need only two so how can i do that?is there any why to take profile from (**profile**.mysite.com) to index.php? **profile**=345 so that when user set demo.mysite.com/2134 it will go and rewrite like - index.php?demo=2134